# Pandas multiple column intersection ignoring na values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with multiple columns,

```
    data={'NAME':['A','B','C'],
  'A':[[1,2,3],[np.nan],[3,4,5]],
  'B':[[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[np.nan]],
    'C':[[2,4],[3],[6,7]]  }
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df=df[['A','B','C']]
```

I can take the intersection of columns using,

```
df.assign(D=df.apply(
    lambda x: list(set(x.A).intersection(set(x.B)).intersection(set(x.C))),
    axis=1))
```

This creates a column D with,

```
 D
[2]
[]
[]
```

But I want to ignore cells with na values and get the intersection, 
Expected output is,

```
 D
[2]
[3]
[]
```

How to do this? 
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way

```
In [72]: df.apply(lambda x: list(set.intersection(*map(set,  
                                      (v for v in x if not all (np.isnan(v)))
                                  ))
                             ), axis=1)
Out[72]:
0    [2]
1    [3]
2     []
dtype: object
```

Answer (score -1):

ok,  I see how the intersection of the first row is 2,  but how is the intersection of the 2nd row columns only "3"?

[image]

Comment: `    data={'NAME':['A','B','C'],
  'A':[[1,2,3],[np.nan],[3,4,5]],
  'B':[[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[np.nan]],
    'C':[[2,4],[3],[6,7]]  }
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df=df[['A','B','C']]